# On Windows, stat and GetFileAttributes fail for paths containing strange characters

Tags: c++, windows

The code below demonstrates how stat and GetFileAttributes fail when the path contains some strange (but valid) ASCII characters.
As a workaround, I would use the 8.3 DOS file name. But this does not work when the drive has 8.3 names disabled. 
(8.3 names are disabled with the fsutil command: fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1).

Is it possible to get stat and/or GetFileAttributes to work in this case?
If not, is there another way of determining whether or not a path is a directory or file?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlpath.h>

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

// The final characters in the path below are 0xc3 (Ã) and 0x3f (?).
// Create a test directory with the name Ã and set TEST_DIR below to your test directory.
const char* TEST_DIR = "D:\\tmp\\VisualStudio\\TestProject\\ConsoleApplication1\\test_data\\Ã"; 

int main()
{
    std::string testDir = TEST_DIR;

    // test stat and _wstat
    struct stat st;
    const auto statSucceeded = stat(testDir.c_str(), &st) == 0;
    if (!statSucceeded)
    {
        printf("stat failed\n");
    }

    std::wstring testDirW = s2ws(testDir);

    struct _stat64i32 stW;
    const auto statSucceededW = _wstat(testDirW.data(), &stW) == 0;
    if (!statSucceededW)
    {
        printf("_wstat failed\n");
    }

    // test PathIsDirectory
    const auto isDir = PathIsDirectory(testDirW.c_str()) != 0;
    if (!isDir)
    {
        printf("PathIsDirectory failed\n");
    }

    // test GetFileAttributes
    const auto fileAttributes = ::GetFileAttributes(testDirW.c_str());
    const auto getFileAttributesWSucceeded = fileAttributes != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES;
    if (!getFileAttributesWSucceeded)
    {
        printf("GetFileAttributes failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"strange (but valid) ASCII characters"* -- ASCII only defines characters for the range 0x00 through 0x7f. 0xc3 is not within the domain of ASCII.

Comment: _Win_ specific workaround: use `wchar_t` instead of `char` (or even better: [\[MSDN\]: TCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx)), and also use [\[MSDN\]: GetFileAttributesW function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx) (and [\[MSDN\]: _wstat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx)) __explicitly__ (no `s2ws`, `wstring`, ...).

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have encountered comes from using  the MultiByteToWideChar function. Using CP_ACP can default to a code page that does not support some characters. If you change the default system code page to UTF8, your code will work. Since you cannot tell your clients what code page to use,  you can use a third party library such as International Components for Unicode to convert from the host code page to UTF16.

I ran your code using console code page 65001 and VS2015 and your code worked as written. I also added positive printfs to verify that it did work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't start with a narrow string literal and try to convert it, start with a wide string literal - one that represents the actual filename.  You can use hexadecimal escape sequences to avoid any dependency on the encoding of the source code.

If the actual code doesn't use string literals, the best resolution depends on the situation; for example, if the file name is being read from a file, you need to make sure that you know what encoding the file is in and perform the conversion accordingly.

If the actual code reads the filename from the command line arguments, you can use wmain() instead of main() to get the arguments as wide strings.